# Can I store a repeating sql query separately and call them inside a function in model - Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

**My current model is somewhat like**

```
class select extends CI_Model{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();}

    public function get_a(){
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('table1');
            $this->db->join('table2','table1.id = 
           table2.id');
            $this->db->where('x',1);

    }


    public function get_b(){
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('table1');
            $this->db->join('table2','table1.id = 
           table2.id');
            $this->db->where('x',2);

    }


    public function get_c(){
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('table1');
            $this->db->join('table2','table1.id = 
           table2.id');
            $this->db->where('x',3);

    }
```

As you can see the same Join operation is repeating in all the three functions. Is there a way which I can just do this join once and use it with the **where clause**

And there are other questions. If that's possible is it efficient than this current method?

Answer (score 0):

Repeating code is wasteful and avoidable. Here is one function that takes an argument to be used with `where`.

```
public function get_x($where){
    $this->db
      ->select('*')
      ->from('table1')
      ->join('table2','table1.id = table2.id')
      ->where('x',$where);
}
```

Comment: This is not what I need to know. As you can see in my above code.. The join query is repeating in all the three functions.

I want to know whether I can use it once to use in all the three functions

Comment: Not just the join - all the code is repeating except for the value to match in the where call.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correct - you can do the following

```
class select extends CI_Model
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_a()
    {
        $this->initializeBaseQuery();
        $this->db->where('x',1);
    }


    public function get_b()
    {
        $this->initializeBaseQuery();
        $this->db->where('x',2);
    }


    public function get_c()
    {
        $this->initializeBaseQuery();
        $this->db->where('x',3);
    }

    private function initializeBaseQuery()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('table1');
        $this->db->join('table2','table1.id = table2.id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem :

> Select modal file :

```
<?php
class Select extends CI_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function get_selection($where = array()){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('table1');
        $this->db->join('table2','table1.id = table2.id', 'left');
        if(!empty($where)) {
            foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
                $this->db->where($key,$value);
            }
        }
        $query_result = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query_result->result();
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

> Text Controller file :

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Test extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        public function get_select(){
            $where = array("x"=>"1"); // you can pass more than one key and value for condition.
            $result =$this->select->get_selection($where);
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($result);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I Hope it will help you.